# Can't realloc and SPL transfer in the same instruction

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, anchor-spl

I am trying to transfer an SPL token, and reallocating space in a PDA in one instruction.

I am able to realloc (increase and decrease) if I remove the token transfer code in the instruction. I'm also able to do the token transfer by itself if I remove the realloc.

But if I combine them both I can only increase the PDA's size, not decrease, and I get the error `[Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match]`.

Can anyone explain what's happening? Here's the code:

```
use anchor_spl::{
  associated_token::AssociatedToken,
  token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer as SplTransfer},
};

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(description: String)]
pub struct EditProfile<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub owner: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(mut)]
  pub token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

  #[account(mut,
    associated_token::mint = token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = owner,
  )]
  pub owner_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

  #[account(mut, seeds = [b"user", owner.key().as_ref()], bump)]
  pub user: Account<'info, User>,

  // 
  #[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = owner,
    associated_token::mint = token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = user,
  )]
  pub user_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [b"profile", owner.key().as_ref()],
    bump,
    realloc = 8 + Profile::BASE_SIZE + description.len(),
    realloc::payer = owner,
    realloc::zero = false,
  )]
  pub profile: Account<'info, Profile>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
  pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
  pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
  pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

pub fn edit_profile(
  ctx: Context<EditProfile>,
  description: String,
) -> Result<()> {
  let profile = &mut ctx.accounts.profile;

  profile.edit(description);

  // instruction works if this is removed:
  token::transfer(
    CpiContext::new(
      ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
      SplTransfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.owner_ata.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.user_ata.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
      }
    ),
    COST_TO_EDIT_PROFILE,
  )?;

  Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `init_if_needed` and just doing either `init` or initializing the ATA ahead of time, for testing purposes?